# Can't access nested JSON Objects in React

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs

I have a simple React Component, and am trying to display a nested JSON object in `render`.

```
// React Component

class NodeDetail extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const node = {};

    this.state = {
      node
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    Node.getNode(this.props.node_id).then((result) => {
      console.log(result.data);
      this.setState(() => ({node: result.data}));
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // TODO: handle error
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.node.node_status.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default NodeDetail;
```

This is the JSON(stored in `result.data`) getting returned from a rails API(some fields removed for brevity):

```
{  
   "id":1234,
   "name":"some-node",
   "created_at":"2018-05-18T15:23:24.012Z",
   "hostname":"some-host",
   "ip":"10.XXX.XXX.XXX",
   "mac":"24:6e:96:XX:11:XX",
   "node_status":{  
      "id":2,
      "name":"Parked"
   }
}
```

When I access the root level attributes in React with `this.state.node.mac` , it returns `24:6e:96:XX:11:XX`.

When I try to access the `name` attribute in `node_status` using `this.state.node.node_status.name`, I get the the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

I have also tried `this.state.node['node_status'].name`, and same error.

Why can't I access this object in the JSON, when clearly it is there?

Comment: What does `this.state.node.node_status` return?

Comment: @LGSon `this.state.node.node_status` returns `undefined`. But it is actually present. Verified this with `console.log(result.data);`

Comment: And as a test, what if you only grab the `node_status`, like this, `this.setState(() => ({node: result.data.node_status}));` and then do `this.state.node.name`

Comment: Given _@user_'s answer below, when you tried `this.state.node.mac` (which you wrote worked), did you do that within the `render` method as well?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I bet it's because your call to the Rails API is asynchronous -- so your `NodeDetail` component tries to render before the API returns data / state is set with the `result.data`...try putting in a condition for non-existent `node_status` as some of the other answers have suggested.

So the current (wrong) data flow will be:

1. `constructor`. `state` is set to `{node: {}}`
2. `componentDidMount`. Calls API.
3. `render`. Throws exception because `this.state.node.node_status` is `undefined`. Component breaks and won't render again...
4. API returns. `state` is set to `result.data`. `result.data` gets logged to your console.

What you can do is something like:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.node.node_status) {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.node.node_status.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Or any of the other suggestions to account for the `undefined` value of `this.state.node.node_status`.

In general, you need to make sure that your `render` method will work, even with the default `state` values set in your `constructor`.

Comment: It is an async call, and node_status is required(there is a DB constraint). If `console.log(result.data);` is showing node_status is present, i don't think this is a race condition.

Comment: It's not a "race condition", it's async Javascript...React will try to render your component before your API returns data, so it doesn't know that there is a DB constraint. It's basically guaranteed that rendering the component in the browser will be faster than your API...

Comment: With React, you need to make sure that `render` will always work, even if the method uses your default `state` values.

Comment: Then how do you explain that `this.state.node.mac` works, which is the immediate preceding object property of `node_status`?

Comment: Because you log `this.state.node.mac` **after** the API returns data. If you try to log `this.state.node.mac` in your `render` method, it will also fail....try it :-)

Comment: Okay, I guess that was an assumption on my part, of where you logged `this.state.node.mac`. I thought I had seen it in the code you posted, but that was just `result.data`. So -- my question should have been, "where in the code are you verifying that `this.state.node.mac` works?"

Comment: @user I am not the OP, and did just do that too (asked where that were verified), in a general comment

Comment: I had `{this.state.node.mac}` in render(before putting node_status), and it worked. Checking the variable if `undefined` is working for me, although I don't really understand how.

Answer (score 5):

Error is coming correct Your are fetching `data` after component loaded  In short you are calling your API in `componentDidMount`
You can get rid off from this error in this way

```
 <div>
        {this.state.node.node_status?this.state.node.node_status.name:""}
 </div>
```

and I would suggest you to  call fetch data API in `componentWillMount` or `constructor` which is the initial stage of `component`.

Comment: This resolved it, in my case I was doing {row.product_feed.id ? row.product_feed.id : "-"} and it was saying the id was undefined. Scale back the check to row.product_feed and boom it works.

Comment: Happy to hear this!.

Comment: was struggling with this myself and this worked for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In render

`newsapi_news.spacy_tags`  is an `[object object]`

`newsapi_news.spacy_tags.all_tags` THROWS can not read prop of undefined error

But this will work

```
data-tag={(newsapi_news.spacy_tags) ? newsapi_news.spacy_tags.all_tags : ""}
```

Code in render must be "compiled" or mounted or whatever the term is and the parent element is not defined yet but the parent of the parent is

Comment: This is perfect, did not think of it :)

Answer (score 0):

Only solution that worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51175467

Issue is that JSON objects can be accessed one-level deep before they are populated, so it is not breaking your webpage until you try to access a nested attribute.